# HP Zbook G3 17 caps lock blinking 5 times

Tags: laptop, bios, laptop-repair, hp-laptop, hp

HP Zbook G3 17 caps lock blinking 5 times
I was trying to clear the bios password as i forgot it i followed some instruction from some tech but it's now only caps lock blinking 5 times then fan go fast , i removed the ram beeps , then i tried again with ram but still the same 5 blinking
Any suggestions?

Comment: Power off and disconnect the power cable, then press the power button for about 30 seconds.

Comment: I did that and the caps lock blinking for long one time only , and after i switch the laptop on it keep the same 5 blinking in caps and num lock

Comment: Your computer needs repairs.

Comment: I will , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

5 blinks indicates a general failure with the motherboard.
That may not be what the actual problem is but it is what that code means.

I would try the advice from @harrymc which is to disconnect the power cable and hold down the power button for 30ish seconds.

If that doesn't work, you can always try to remove the battery and try the same.  You can find how to get to the battery from the manual under "Removing a user-replaceable battery".  I myself could not get the back to re-latch after removing the bottom cover so be careful.

1. Caps Lock/Num Lock   CPU CPU not functional
2. Caps Lock/Num Lock   BIOS    BIOS corruption failure
3. Caps Lock/Num Lock   Memory  Module error not functional
4. Caps Lock/Num Lock   Graphics    Graphics controller not functional
5. Caps Lock/Num Lock   System board    General system board failure
6. Caps Lock/Num Lock   BIOS    BIOS authentication failure

Comment: I did that and the caps lock blinking for long one time only , and after i switch the laptop on it keep the same 5 blinking in caps and num lock

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion : The problem is clearly hardware, but I do not presume
to indicate how to repair your computer yourself.
This is rather a job for the repair-shop.

The repair-shop will have enough replacement parts to isolate the problem
with a minimal exchange of components.